# How Do I Create an "Any Logged-In User" Policy With PostgreSQL Row-Level Security

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I'm trying to create a policy that let's any logged-in user create a record in a "resources" table.  I can create the policy just fine:

```
CREATE POLICY insert_resources
ON public.resources
FOR INSERT TO public_user WITH CHECK (
    (NULLIF(CURRENT_SETTING('jwt.claims.person_id', true), '')) IS NOT NULL
)
```

However, I must be doing something wrong, because when I try to do an INSERT as a logged-in user, I get a "permission denied for table resources" aclcheck_error.

I'm pretty sure that's the only relevant policy, because when I run:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_policies
WHERE tablename = 'resources'
    AND cmd='INSERT';
```

... it's the only policy that shows up.

Can any PostgreSQL (row-level security) experts help explain what's wrong with my policy?

Comment: RLS policies are not the only thing relevant. Did you actually [grant the `INSERT` privilege on that table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) to the `public_user` user?

Comment: That was my problem, thank you.  If you could put that in the form of an answer, I'd happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "*permission denied for table*" error sounds like you didn't [`GRANT` the `INSERT` privilege on that table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) to the `public_user` user.